# How To Reset Location Without Resetting Pivot Point

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to reset the location of my object without resetting the pivot point.

I know you can do CTRL+A to reset the location, but that also resets the pivot point to 0,0,0

How can I move around my objcect anywhere I want and set that location to 0,0,0 while keeping the pivot point where it is? (because as you can see in the image, the location isn't at 0,0,0)

Thanks[image]

My goal with this is to make it so the fence sits perfeclty on the cube (which is at 0,0,0) as shown here (I need the pivot point to be at the bottom left so that I can rotate the fence around that point) :

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Alt`+`G` will set it to world origin.

Comment: @Harry McKenzie yeah, but I want to make it so the origin isn't at (0,0,0) but at (0,0,1) for example, so that when I move it to world position of (0,0,2) the object's position will be (0,0,1) relative to it's origin

Comment: Reset the origin to 0, 0, 0, then in edit mode move everything up one unit

Comment: But that would result in the pivot point being at (0,0,0)

Comment: If the origin is already where you want it, just select All in Edit mode and move it where you want. The origin will stay in the same place.

Comment: Yes, the origin will stay in the same world space, but since I want the object to rotate around the pivot point I assigned this isn't an ideal solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you will have to come to terms with while using Blender is the difference between  *Object* and *Mesh*.

Object is word that means a bundle of a ton of Blender data-blocks all packaged around an origin as the 0 point for it's Local transforms.

[image]

If I enter edit mode, delete everything and then back into object mode, you can see that I still have that object in the outliner. The "Object" data-block still exists, it just has a mesh (AKA Object Data) with 0 vertices.

[image]

When you press Alt+G all that does is clear the object origin and set it back to 0,0,0 in World Space.

Whenever you Tab into edit mode you'll notice in the outliner that the object data block has an edit mode icon next to it and the Mesh Data Block lights up. That means you are only editing the data itself, not the object and it's origin.

*Moving the vertices within the Mesh/Object-data datablock while in edit mode, the Object datablock remains untouched.*

[image]

So if you want to set the object origin to be 0,0,0 and then manipulate the geometry without messing up the origin, you just need to be sure you are only working in edit mode.

If you mess it up then just use Shift+S > Cursor to World Origin, and then Object> Origin to Cursor to set that there, that or Ctrl+A > Apply Location.

[image]

[image]

[image]

While editing you rarely use the object origin as a pivot for transforms. Thats what the 3D Cursor is for. You push `.` to change the pivot point.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like to be really careful not mixing "reset" and "apply" together. To "reset" something means to roll it back to where it was. In the case of location, it means moving the origin back to its 0:0:0 coordinates - which corresponds to the world center when not parented to something elsewhere. Applying means to change the origin of the object and put it at the world center, while keeping the object's content wherever it is.

Comment: Shoot lemme edit that.

Comment: This is so well put together! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your trying to do but the answers above are all correct.
0,0,0, is a fixed position. You cannot make any other position location 0,0,0, for anything.
Right of 0,0,0, is X1,2,3 etc. Left is X-1,-2,-3,Towards you is Y-1,-2,-3, n away from you is Y1,2,3. You can position things by grid units like 10 units X n -Y units 3 or you can just eyeball it.
If you are are doing some kind of animation or taking different shots and moving things from one point to another to pivot on the cube. I suggest you place "Empty" as a marker where you want the fence to be 1st then another "Empty" position on the top of the cube where you want to pivot at. Put your fence where you want its to be, Shift S to put the cursor at the fence's Origin at the bottom left as you wanted n add a "Empty" to the "Cursor". Do the same for all the other locations. Now you can move around for different shots and the cube will be at all the right positions you want. Just move "Cursor" to "Empty" n then Fence to "Cursor". Can do the same with Key Framing positions too but not know what you are trying to do, This is the best I can come up with.

Comment: Make sure you are answering the question the OP is asking, and that you are sure that your answer can solve their specific issue before posting. Answer shouldn't be guesses.